# How to show error messages and icon when submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

I cannot execute my JS code on my html by the following code. It works when I change 'submit' to 'input' for addEventListener.

```
  <form action="#" id="form">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" >
  <button type="submit" class="arrow"><img src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="submit"></button>
  <img src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="error" id="error-arrow" class = "hidden">
  
  <p id="error-message" class="hidden">Please provide a valid email.</p>
  </form>
```

```
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const error = document.getElementById('error-message');
const errorArrow = document.getElementById('error-arrow')
const form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
        
        error.classList.remove('hidden');
        errorArrow.classList.remove('hidden');
        
    } else {
        email.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled `submit`,
`sumbit` should be `submit`
See if that fixes the error

Comment: I have fixed, however the warning message in <p> does not show :(